# Removing a Given Key from a Groovy Map

Tags: dictionary, groovy, httprequest

I'm sure this is a very simple question, but I'm very new to Groovy and it's something I've been struggling with for awhile now. I have an `HttpServletRequest` and I need to do something with it's parameters. However, I want to exclude exactly 1 parameter.

Previously, I was using

```
req.getParameterMap
```

However, to remove the one value, I'm trying something along the lines of

```
def reqParams = req.getParameterMap?.remove('blah');
```

I know that the above does not quite work, but that's the psuedo-code for what I'm trying to achieve. I really need the new Map and the original `req.getParameterMap()` Objects to look exactly the same except for the one missing key. What's the best way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you use grails or just add groovy support to your java app?

Comment: Just being used within a java app.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`req.getParameterMap` returns an immutable map which cannot be modified. You need to create a new map, `putAll` from the parameter map and remove the required key you do not want.

```
def reqParams = [:] << req.getParameterMap()
reqParams.remove('blah')
```

You have your new map as `reqParams` (without the undesired key value pair) and the original parameter map.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `findAll` function, somethig like:

```
def map = req.getParameterMap().findAll {it.key != 'blah'}
```

Comment: I like this answer much better as it is easily generalized (for example) to remove all keys **beginning with** `blah`, as in: `def map = req.getParameterMap().findAll {!it.key.startsWith('blah')}`

Comment: Nice, but it's a real pitty they didn't make `map - key` work also :D (notice that `map - [key: 'value']` works but you need to know the value, not just the key)