# Best way to remove property from groovy object list

Tags: groovy

I have an object list-

```
  List<Person> personList = [ 
      {name: "a" , age:20 },
      {name: "b" , age:24 },
      {name: "c" , age:25 },
      {name: "d" , age:26 },
   ]
```

**Now, what is the shortest way to remove `age` from each object?**

Final list will be:

```
 personList =  [ 
      {name: "a" },
      {name: "b" },
      {name: "c" },
      {name: "d" },
   ]
```

Comment: What's the data type of your objects?

Comment: @ernest_k Collection

Comment: I meant the inner objects, like `{name: "a" , age:20 }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing a Given Key from a Groovy Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860826/removing-a-given-key-from-a-groovy-map)

Comment: "what is the shortest way to remove age from each object?" - Do you want to remove `age` from each of the nested `Map` or do you want to create new `Map`s that are copies of the original except `age` is omitted?

Comment: @ernest_k edited the question. One way to do it is by using DTO and iterating but I do not want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit *syntax lift up* your example works using `findAll`

```
def x = [ 
      [name: "a" , age:20 ],
      [name: "b" , age:24 ],
      [name: "c" , age:25 ],
      [name: "d" , age:26 ]
   ]
 

println x.collect {it.findAll {it.key != 'age'}} 

[[name:a], [name:b], [name:c], [name:d]]
```

Comment: "...what is the shortest way to remove age from each object?" - I don't think this example removes age.  I think it creates new `Map` instances that don't contain the age.

Comment: Correct @JeffScottBrown this is the *immutable* solution.

Comment: "Correct @JeffScottBrown this is the immutable solution." - Agreed.  I am just pointing out that nothing is being removed.  Unclear if the question was poorly worded, or if the intent is to remove the elements.  As it is, the original Maps still contain the `age` and the wording of the question makes it unclear if that is desired or not.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should not create a List with type of `Person` (unknown class) and fill it with Maps without cast.

With Maps you have at least 2 simple options.

Option 1 - create a new List:

```
personList = personList.collect{ [ name:it.name ] }
```

Option 2 - mutate the existing List:

```
personList*.remove( 'age' )
```